# Import Objective C class to swift cannot #import base class

Tags: objective-c, swift

We have a class like this defined in Objective C.

```
#import "MTLModel.h"
@interface Foo : MTLModel
...
@end
```

which works totally fine until when we want to use the class in Swift and put this header file `foo.h` in the `bridge-header.h`, it begins to have a compile error saying that we cannot `#import "MTLModel.h"`.

> "MTLModel.h" file not found

[image]

Why?

---

Edit:

A work around that I find is to replace `#import MTLModel.h` with `@class MTLModel;` and it works. But I still have no clue why it is the way it is.

---

Edit 2:

We understand why it works without the include header. It is because we already put this `#import "Mantle/MTLModel.h"` in the precompile headers file. Or in another work, we don't need to put `@class MTLModel;` there either. We can replace `#import "MTLModel.h"` with `#import "Mantle/MTLModel.h"` and it also works.

The only thing that we don't quite understand is why the original `#import "MTLModel.h"`. But it is less important at this point, we may have a include path for that.

Comment: Do you check target for `MTLModel` and your new file

Comment: `MTLModel.h` is part of the Mantle project. How are you bringing that lib into your project?

Comment: @DaveWeston yes, we do have that in our library.

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski I am not sure I understand what you mean ..

Comment: Are you using a dependency manager like cocoapods or Carthage? Or are you using a submodule, or embedding the code in your project?

Comment: We are using cocoapods, that's should be fine. We've been using it for a while and MTLModel works fine in both ObjectiveC and Swift for us. It is just that this class that we defined in Objective C that is imported to Swift in the bridge header and we see this problem...